# Electromagnetic Waves (Microwaves)- Does the effect of rain on a wave in point A impact it in point B

Tags: communication, wireless, electromagnetic

I'm trying to find the answer to this question with no luck. If a wave is traveling across a distance with Points A and B... and there is rain or some other factor of fading/absorption in point A.... will it impact point B where it's not raining? (Assuming distance covered by propagating wave has some rain in A and no rain in B).

Therefore, the Question is essentially asking whether whatever happens in point A of wave1 does or doesn't impact point B of wave1 in free space.

Example: Would I still be able to receive the signal with same strength in point B even though point A in propagation path of wave is fading due to rain or other damping?

Your answers would very much be appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: 1. A drawing would be helpful 2. "Electromagnetic Wave" is a very broad concept, that covers e.g. also visible light. What frequency range are you interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in microwaves. I just included that in the question for clarification. Thanks

Comment: The geometry is still nit clear. Where is the transmitter? Where is the receiver? Where is point A?  Where is point B? We can not read your mind.

Comment: I just included a rough pic I sketched from phone to show what I mean.

Comment: We can assume they are a few Kilometers away from each other.

Comment: The answer is maybe, it is frequency dependent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Roughly speaking anything between transmitter TX and A does not affect the signal from going from TX to B.

This is, however, not completely true:
There are two exceptions:

- If the obstracle comes too close to the line of sight between TX and B it *does* affect signal propagation between TX and B even if it is well off the line of sight.
  The "sensitive" volume between TX and B is called the [Fresnel Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone).
- If there is [multi path propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation) by reflection at the obstractle. It  may cause destructive interference at B.

Comment: Thanks a heap Curd. So just to make sure I understand this, no matter what the obstacle is outside of the Fresnel zone, it won't impact the signal? Even a change in the EM field or wave energy outside of this zone, won't carry the influence to the rest of the signal by decreasing overall energy?

Comment: Yes, that's right (with the exception I mentioned: e.g. if you reflect the signal from TX via obstacle to B; that's called [multi path propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation) which can cause (destructive) interference)

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. Please bear with me on another Question to confirm my understanding. So if the scenario now that both the Tx and Rx (B) are in closer distance and point A (obstacle) is behind Rx(B).... Even though obstacle and B Rx ((are)) within line of sight by a few Kilometers.. what would happen? Would Obstacle still impact it even its farther from Tx than B is? (But still in line of sight) - Pic above to demonstrate

Comment: It could fall into category of the 2nd exception, i.e. it could be a reflector (e.g. a metal sheet or mesh) that reflects the signal back to the receiver. Depending on the wavelength and distance between receiver and reflector you can get constructive or destructive interference.; but you could make the receiver sensitive only for signal coming from RX by shielding its back.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great. Thanks Curd for your time. Appreciated very much.